# Transfer data using Android intent vs. data objects in application class

Tags: android, android-intent

I have to transfer objects between activities.
Objects are with complex structure.
I'm not sure what to do: to add bundle to intent or to store data in application class.
Which method is better /performance and garbage produced/?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The safest method is to bundle the data to pass with the `Intent`. This will be re-usable and avoid cluttering the global object space of the application. However this method is *slightly* more time consuming in that you have to implement [`Serializable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) for your custom types or create a custom [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html).